# How to dynamically bind jndi name with datasource initialized by spring for use in log4j2 jdbcappender?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jndi, log4j2

contextlisteneroverride

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("context has started");
        super.contextInitialized(event);
        System.out.println(context.class.getName());
//      Logger logme=LogManager.getLogger();
//      Logger logme1=LogManager.getLogger("context-fileappend");
//      logme.info("This is context logger"+this.toString());
//      logme1.info("This is fileappend"+this.toString());
//      final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
//        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
//        Appender x=
//        config.
        //dostuff();
        Context initCtx;
        try {
            initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context springCtx = initCtx.createSubcontext("spring");
            Object bean=WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).getBean(createdatasrc.class);
            System.out.println(event.getServletContext().getMajorVersion()+" "+event.getServletContext().getMinorVersion());
            springCtx.bind("bean", bean);
//START LOG4J INITIALIZATION FROM HERE
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //BasicDataSource
    }
```

WEB.XML

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/data.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


  <listener>
<listener-class>log4j.sessionmgr</listener-class>
</listener>

 <listener>
        <listener-class>log4j.context</listener-class>
    </listener>




  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping> 

   <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

DATA.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="data" class="log4j.createdatasrc"></bean>
</beans>
```

CREATEDATASRC.JAVA

```
public class createdatasrc extends BasicDataSource {

    public static int count=0;
    public createdatasrc()
    {
        count++;
        this.setMaxIdle(10);
        this.setMaxTotal(-1);
        this.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-5N44AE\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=woah");
        this.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        this.setUsername("sa");
        this.setPassword("pass");
        System.out.println("datasource created");

    }

}
```

PART OF LOG4J.XML

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="logs">
      <DataSource jndiName="spring/bean" />
      <Column name="eventDate" isEventTimestamp="true" />
      <Column name="level" pattern="%level" />
      <Column name="logger" pattern="%logger" />
      <Column name="message" pattern="%message" />
      <Column name="exception" pattern="%ex{full}" />
    </JDBC>
```

In the above log4j.xml the jdbc appender requires a jndi name for the data source, problem is the datasource creation will be happening dynamically during the applicationcontext initialization as can be seen in the web.xml,following which I will be binding the the jndi name with the datasource object during the servletcontext initialization. So essentially when log4j starts the jndi name is unbounded which is causing the error that jndi name is not found. Questions:

- How to delay startup of log4j2 and fire initialization process from code?
- Is it possible in spring to initialize a bean(createdatasrc) before log4j2 starts?
- Tried changing the listener for the log4j2,but still its initialization process starts before the applicationcontext initialization.Why order of listeners is not followed?
- jdbcappender createbuilder is deperecated,would it possible to use the jdbcappender constructor and manually add the appender to the config?
- Is there a easier way to do this without changing the fact that datasource will be initialized dynamically by the spring?
- When setting the context param isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled to true and the Log4jServletContextListener provided in the web.xml, the log4j2 is still able to start using the default configuration as seem in the tomcat console,is this the defined behavior?
- I have also tried creating the datasource during the applicationcontext initialization but log4j2 starts even before that,causing the jndi lookup to fail, so where am I going wrong in using the param isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled and how do I manually start the initialization process in code?
- Env:- Using Tomcat 9 with servlet version 4.0 with maven webapp-archtype in Eclipse IDE.